# What is the best way to load shared data into an actor?

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor computing data on one side, call it A. On the other side, I have actor B which receives the data from actor A. The whole purpose of B is to check if the data is relevant and act on that, ie. Actor B has to load data from a DB source and compare it with the result from A.

The data loaded by B changes nearly never. It has to be loaded once when the application is started and then the actor should use whatever cache version it can.

Is there a way to do this with Akka ?

Answer (score 0):

Just send a message from A to B when you have computed the data. After that, B can either switch to "verified" or to "unverified" state depending on verification results, and react on the subsequent messages depending on its state.

An example of how to handle the different states with extra information:

```
class MyDBActor extends Actor {
  def receive = starting
  def starting = {
    case data:DataFromA => 
        dbData = <load data from DB>
        if (<data is OK>)
           context.become(verified(dbData))
        else
           context.become(unverified)
  }
  def verified(dbData:DataFromDB) = {
    case whatevermessage => 
      < do something with message and data>
  }
  def unverified => {
    case _ => <throw exception, log unverified access, etc>
  }
}
```

Another option might be to use DB data in order to instantiate a new actor, which would be instantiated if and only the data is correct, and make other parts of program trying to talk to this actor. If the data is not verified, the actor would not exist (but you'll get to deal with exceptions somehow).

Comment: I agree on that but how do you get the data from DB in B? Do I have to load them on each received message?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.